# Absolute continuity: Why are indices (x_1,...,x_{2n}) rather than (x_1,...,x_n)?

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking at a continuity proof in Borden's *A Course In Advanced Calculus* and came across a definition which confused me:

Let $D\subset E^m$ and $f:D\rightarrow E^m$ be a mapping. $f$ is *absolutely continuous* on $D$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ s.t. for every $(x_1,...,x_{2n})\subset D$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\rho(x_{2i},x_{2i-1})<\delta$ 
 then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\rho(f(x_{2i}),f(x_{2i-1}))<\epsilon$

Why is it that the index runs from $(x_1,...,x_{2n})$ rather than $(x_1,...,x_{n})$?

I recognize this concept from undergrad calc but I am a little new to this level of rigor.

Comment: Note that the sums use up the $x_i$'s two at a time, so you need an even number of them.

Comment: But why not use $(x_1,...,x_n)\subset D$ and then sum $\rho(f(x_{n},x_{n-1})$? I am having difficulty understanding the physical interpretation of having those indices doubled.

Comment: It's really a collection of $n$ pairs $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\ldots,x_n,y_n$, but they have chosen to use only the letter $x$ instead of both $x$ and $y$. The is no physical meaning, note that there is no relationship between $n$ or $m$ implied here.